# ClassCastException while reading data from Hive

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I have created a Hive table like this

```
CREATE TABLE SpaceWalk (astronaut String, timeSpent int) 
COMMENT 'Extra Vehicular Activity Done By Astronauts' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE 
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/NASA';
```

I loaded the table with a sequence file (which is the output of a mapreduce job) that has key-value pairs in Text-IntWritable format respectively.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/srimanth/HiveSeq.data' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE SpaceWalk;
```

In hdfs the file is present in the location I specified while creating the table. But when I tried to read the data I am getting ClassCastException.

```
hive> SELECT * FROM SpaceWalk;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.BinaryComparable
Time taken: 0.354 seconds
```

The sequnce file is displaying the keys and values properly when I view from hdfs.

```
anil@srimanthpc:~$ hdfs dfs -text /user/hive/warehouse/NASA/HiveSeq.data
15/08/03 20:05:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Akihiko Hoshide 1283
Al Worden   39
Alan Shepard    567
Aleksei Yeliseyov   37
Alexander Kaleri    1318
Alexander Misurkin  394
Alexander Samokutyaev   383
```

and there are like 100 more key-value pairs are there in that which I am not showing here.

I appreciate some help. Thank you.

Edits: I gave '\011' for FILEDS TERMINATED BY but nothing changed :(

Comment: when you load the data, are you getting any error? If no error, is the count showing that records are present. If count also shows up, then is **select** causing the issue?

Comment: count also throwing the same exception

Comment: ok so the issue could be due to data loading. From the error I can see that Classcast exception from integer(in your table column definition) to binary(sequence file). So it can be identifying delimiter or type of sequence file used(like is it valid file format) or as last option , you can try with string in hive and see if that is an issue

Comment: I tried this. Instead of using LOAD DATA, I manually inserted a row using insert into table_name. Sequence file got generated in hdfs hive warehouse location. The header contains BytesWritable and Text not what I am expecting. So I copied that file locally and then created duplicate table and loaded using LOAD DATA LOCAL with sequence file which I just copied, now select and everything works fine. So the sequence file which I am trying to load initially has Text and Intwritable in it's header. So it looks you can only load the sequence file data which is in BytesWritable and Text.

Comment: so its more like a format issue.